# Too many characters in character literal in my delete syntax

Tags: c#, database

the commented code are working but do not refresh it as soon as possible and this not `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID2",  '" + dataGridView5.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "');`

```cs
    private void button4_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        disp_data();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXYZZ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=rick_inventiory;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete from tbl_Orders where CustomerID2 = '" + dataGridView5.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
        con.Open();
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID2", txtCustomerID2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID2",  '" + dataGridView5.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "');
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();         
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");              
    }
```

Comment: single quotes ' in C# is used for chars. For String you need to use: double quotes "

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending

```
 dataGridView5.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

as a string

Use

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID2",  dataGridView5.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```